# How to enable some dates which is disabled by the daysDisabled property in ngx-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

daysDisabled property disabled all the given days. For example if i supply [0], then it disable all the sunday.
I want that some of the dates should be enabled which is disabled by daysDisabled.
We have datesEnabled property which enable dates but it disabled all the dates other than what we suppy in the datesEnabled. so datesEnabled is not fit here

I tried datesEnabled but does not fit here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.